# What is the best way to connect two applications using APIs? (An E-commerce and a chatbot)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two applications settled  up. One is a E-commerce (TrayCommerce) that has itself an API (Oauth), from which I can get order, clients, products information, etc. The other one is a chatbot (Take Blip).
My goal is to make the chatbot retrieve information from the e-commerce's API so I can send it to final user.
I thought in two ways of doing it:

1. Hosting a JavaScript code inside the bot, so I can call the API whenever user requests data. However, I don't know how to implement the authentication flow on this approach and how I would, in the future, set up a system to receive notifications from the API to send information each time it is updated, since I can only host one js file per action.
2. Creating a NodeJS API, which will be hosted on a third party, and that will return the information I want, in a formatted way, to the chatbot. I don't know if this is over-engineering, because I already have an API from the e-commerce.

I am sorry if it is a dumb question, I am new to web development, but any information would be valuable for me to choose a workflow for this integration.

Comment: Hi, congratulations for your first question! What kind of OAuth flows does the API support? (client credentials, auth code, etc)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to answer, the right question to ask yourself is the **sensitiveness** of the data inside the e-commerce; and the **power** granted to the generated token in the auth implementation.

Typically, a chatbot (assuming a web one) is a piece of Javascript held in the client (browser). This piece of code is perfectly readable by the user, thus you have to assume the generated token could be used to perform a request that you didn't intended him to perform.

So as a simple answer :

- If — and only if — the implemented OAuth mecanism lets you limit the scope of authorization to the customer, then you can make the customer authenticate directly with TrayCommerce and the appropriate scopes (and use his token to perform on the API). Said differently, if typically TrayCommerce lets you register your Chatbot as a "client" (this is an OAuth keyword), and generate Auth journeys with appropriate 3-parties flows, granting only something like "orders:view:self" for customers, it's OK.
- If the TrayCommerce API is more like a "management API"; with auth implemented in a way that **you** (yourself, not the customer) have to authenticate on it; then this auth mecanism is not suitable for your use-case. You then have to make an API like you described, that would act like a proxy to TrayCommerce. With considerations (see below).

In the case of you making a "Proxy API" to TrayCommerce; you are basically hiding the TrayCommerce Authentication on your server-side, and shifting that responsibility from TrayCommerce to yourself. In such a case, you have to implement your own authentication (+ authorization) mecanism on this API, to be able not to expose TrayCommerce data to the world.